# Compare two lists in python - check only order

Tags: python, list, compare

I have two lists and I need to return true or false based on the comparision.
I have below rules.

1. Check for the element order, elements need not to be at the exact index
2. There should be no extra non empty elements in the list

> Eg:
> list1 ['a','b','','','d'] and list2 ['a','b','d'] - this should
> be true
>
> list1 ['a','b','','','d'] and list2 ['a','b','c','d'] - this should be
> false
>
> list1 ['a','b','d','',''] and list2 ['a','b','d','c'] - this should be
> false
>
> list1 ['a','b','d','',''] and list2 ['a','b','d',''] - this should be
> true

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: I don't understand. In the first example, first list has `''` and second one dosen't. How is that not a violation of the second rule *"There should be no extra elements in the list"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what i have tried:

```py
def matcher(l1, l2):
    l1 = ' '.join(l1).split()
    l2 = ' '.join(l2).split()
    if l1 == l2:
        return True
    else:
        return False
    
print(matcher(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['d', 'a', 'b', 'c', '']))
```

Output:
`False`

and at the last there're no empty elements either

Answer (score 3):

You could try this:

```py
def check_lst(lst1, lst2):
    lst1 = [string for string in lst1 if string != ""]
    lst2 = [string for string in lst2 if string != ""]

    return lst1 == lst2

print(check_lst(['a','b','','','d'], ['a','b','c','d']))
```

This outputs `False`

What the first 2 lines of the function do is remove all empty strings from a list.

Then, I use a simple if statement to check if the 2 lists match!

Comment: My bad. Just fixed it now. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @YashasviBhatt Why should it be `True`? The question says the elements should be in the same order, not necessarily same index...

Comment: Sorry I misinterpret the question, I think that neither order nor index matters, only elements matters

Comment: @YashasviBhatt No, that doesn't seem true. Read the question's requirements: 1. *"Check for __the element order__, elements need __not__ to be at the __exact index__"* 2. *"There should be no extra elements in the list"*

Comment: btw a further simplification can be: `return lst1 == lst2`

Comment: @quamrana True! I didn't think of that but it would definitely work!